# Visual Studio 2013 High DPI on 4k Screen

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Just bought Dell XPS 15 4k laptop for development.

I am using visual studio 2013 and doing an integration project.  My debugging screen shows almost unreadable text, as I have to copy and paste to another screen to see the errors.  Has anyone have issues with this, and is there a resolution to this problem?  See image...

[image]

Comment: Use Control Panel > Display to bump up the DPI.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: Given the tab text and tool bar look fine I would say that the control panel settings are unlikely to make a difference and this is likely a Visual Studio issue.

Comment: Dpi text is already at custom 250% setting in control panel.  Everything works fine except this piece so far.

Answer (score -1):

There is an easier way in settings.  You have to disable an option.  It worked for me.  It has to do with memory setting.